# Owin web role will not decrypt cookie provided by Owin MVC Application

Tags: authentication, cookies, owin

**MVC Web Application**

I have an MVC 5 website that formerly used FormsAuthentication that I have since switched over to OWIN authentication. Signing in and out of the website with OWIN works correctly. Here is the startup configuration.

```
public partial class Startup
{
    // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/LogOn")
        });
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
    }
```

It has some basic claims setup when logging in...

```
    public void SignIn(string username, bool remember, string userData)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>();

        var user = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VastIdentity>(userData);
        // create *required* claims
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserId.ToString()));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username));

        // custom – serialised user state
        claims.Add(new Claim("userState", userData));

        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

        AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties()
        {
            AllowRefresh = true,
            IsPersistent = remember,
            ExpiresUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7)
        }, identity);
    }
```

This all works fine and the user can sign in and out of the MVC application with an appropriate cookie.

**SignalR Web Role**

I have a separate azure web role that hosts signalr. It has the following startup...

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.Register(typeof(IUserIdProvider), () => new CustomUserIdProvider());

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
            CookieName = ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie",
            Provider = new CustomAuthProvider()
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
            // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
            // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
            // providing a cors options with a different policy.
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                // EnableJSONP = true
            };
            // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
            // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
            // path.
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
}
```

**Problem 1:** When a connection is made to the SignalR hub and OnConnected is called the Context.User.Identity is an empty GenericPrincipal and does not contain the claims from the website cookie. This was why I was going to implement a custom authentication provider and setup the Identity myself. But it doesn't seem to be used.

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    // snip

    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        string name = Context.User.Identity.Name;

        _Connections.Add(name, Context.ConnectionId);

        return base.OnConnected();
    }
  }
```

When I inspect the cookies on the context I can see the encrypted **.AspNet.ApplicationCookie** is being passed along with the request. But I cannot figure out how to get OWIN to decrypt it and use the available claims.

**Problem 2:** The custom auth provider is never run. When  I set break points in it, it never enters either method.

```
public class CustomAuthProvider : CookieAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override void ResponseSignIn(CookieResponseSignInContext context)
    {
        // do some custom stuff here
        base.ResponseSignIn(context);
    }

    public override Task ValidateIdentity(CookieValidateIdentityContext context)
    {
        // do some custom stuff here
        return base.ValidateIdentity(context);
    }
}
```

I haven't had a lot of experience with the OWIN authentication. Can anybody see what may be going wrong on the signalr web role cookie authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After pulling my hair out I re-checked the versions of the owin nugget packages and noticed that the web application was using 3.0.1 whilst the SignalR web role was using 2.x.

**The solution was to make sure the owin libraries were the same version between applications**. It looks as if owin cannot decrypt a cookie generated from a different version.

---

**Edit:** Since the issue decrypting the cookie was related to a version mismatch the custom authentication provider and cookie name was not needed.

This resulted in the following simple owin initializing in the web role...

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Branch the pipeline here for requests that start with "/signalr"
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
            // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
            // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
            // providing a cors options with a different policy.
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                // EnableJSONP = true
            };
            // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
            // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
            // path.
            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
}
```